# Pandas - improve performance when grouping and applying custom function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this. My data size is approximately over 100,000 rows.

| Category | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| A | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| B | 3 | 4 | 1 | 2 |
| B | 1 | 5 | 3 | 1 |

I'd like to group with `Category` column at first, and calculate with my own method in each group.

Custom method returns a float value `cal`.

The desired output is in a dictionary form with results.

```
{ 
    'A': { 'cal': a },
    'B:' { 'cal': b },
    ...
}
```

I tried with `groupby` and `apply` of `pandas`.

```py
def my_cal(df):
    ret = ...
    return {'cal': ret}

df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda grp: my_cal(grp)).to_dict()
```

When I measured a time in jupyter notebook with `timeit`, it takes over 1 second which is too long for me.

Is there a way to optimize this and perform with reduced time?

------------- EDIT -------------

Updated `my_cal`'s arguments from dataframe to array.

```py
def my_cal(val1: float, val2: float, val3: float, val4: float):
    ret = inner_cal(val1, val2, val3, val4) # inner_cal is in external library
    return {'cal': ret}

df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda grp: my_cal(grp['val1'].to_numpy(),
                                                grp['val2'].to_numpy(),
                                                grp['val3'].to_numpy(),
                                                grp['val4'].to_numpy())).to_dict()
```

Comment: You could time `df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda grp: None).to_dict()` - the difference will be your function. You could also remove the to_dict part to see how that is involved.

Comment: @tdelaney I timed that, and it was considerably fast.

Comment: pandas and numpy store and operate on floats efiiciently. Python level floats are much more expensive. Just the overhead of making python floats of your data is a problem. That external library, if there is a way to do the same thing but on entire numpy arrays using numpy ufuncs which understand machine level floats and do things on entire arrays of them, would be the best way to speed this up.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I didn't know there is a gap in costs between numpy and python floats. In an edited `my_cal`, since I passed arrays after using `to_numpy()`, the arguments val1,2,3,4 are actually `np.ndarray` type. (I made a mistake when I added type annotation) and inside `inner_cal()` it deals with `np.ndarray` as well. so I think I'm using floats on numpy on whole code... do you think that I need to replace `inner_cal`?

Comment: I was puzzled about float vs np. pandas wraps numpy and will tend to bunch all float columns into a single np array (this is something of a dark art and I don't kwow all of the rules to that). You may find that just operating on the dataframe is the fastest. But generally, since these are ndarrays, I suspect you are already doing it the faster way

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things you could try:

- Reduce the number of rows, by removing elements with invalid values, prior to applying the group by (if possible).
- Reduce the data frame's memory footprint, by shrinking its columns data types.
- Use [`numba`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/), to generate an optimized machine code version of `my_cal` function.

You can also find additional strategies that you might consider trying here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#

### Shrinking columns data types

The following code enables you to reduce your data frame's memory usage, by converting each column data type to its smallest representation possible. For example, if you have a column with values stored as `int64`, it will try to determine whether the column's values range can be represented as `int8`, `int16`, or `int32`. In addition it can also convert values with `object` data type to `category`, and `int` to `uint`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def df_shrink_dtypes(df, skip=None, obj2cat=True, int2uint=False):
    """
    Try to shrink data types for ``DataFrame`` columns.

    Allows ``object`` -> ``category``, ``int`` -> ``uint``, and exclusion.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        The dataframe to shrink.
    skip : list, default=[]
        The names of the columns to skip.
    obj2cat : bool, default=True
        Whether to cast ``object`` columns to ``category``.
    int2uint : bool, default=False
        Whether to cast ``int`` columns to ``uint``.

    Returns
    -------
    new_dtypes : dict
        The new data types for the columns.
    """
    if skip is None:
        skip = []
    # 1: Build column filter and type-map
    excl_types, skip = {"category", "datetime64[ns]", "bool"}, set(skip)

    typemap = {
        "int": [
            (np.dtype(x), np.iinfo(x).min, np.iinfo(x).max)
            for x in (np.int8, np.int16, np.int32, np.int64)
        ],
        "uint": [
            (np.dtype(x), np.iinfo(x).min, np.iinfo(x).max)
            for x in (np.uint8, np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64)
        ],
        "float": [
            (np.dtype(x), np.finfo(x).min, np.finfo(x).max)
            for x in (np.float32, np.float64, np.longdouble)
        ],
    }
    if obj2cat:
        # User wants to "categorify" dtype('Object'),
        # which may not always save space.
        typemap["object"] = "category"
    else:
        excl_types.add("object")

    new_dtypes = {}
    exclude = lambda dt: dt[1].name not in excl_types and dt[0] not in skip

    for c, old_t in filter(exclude, df.dtypes.items()):
        t = next((v for k, v in typemap.items() if old_t.name.startswith(k)), None)

        # Find the smallest type that fits
        if isinstance(t, list):
            if int2uint and t == typemap["int"] and df[c].min() >= 0:
                t = typemap["uint"]
            new_t = next(
                (r[0] for r in t if r[1] <= df[c].min() and r[2] >= df[c].max()), None
            )
            if new_t and new_t == old_t:
                new_t = None
        else:
            new_t = t if isinstance(t, str) else None
        if new_t:
            new_dtypes[c] = new_t
    return new_dtypes


def df_shrink(df, skip=None, obj2cat=True, int2uint=False):
    """Reduce memory usage, shrinking data types for ``DataFrame`` columns.

    Parameters
    ----------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        The dataframe to shrink.
    skip : list, default=[]
        The names of the columns to skip.
    obj2cat : bool, default=True
        Whether to cast ``object`` columns to ``category``.
    int2uint : bool, default=False
        Whether to cast ``int`` columns to ``uint``.

    Returns
    -------
    df : pandas.DataFrame
        The dataframe with the new data types.

    See Also
    --------
    - :func:`df_shrink_dtypes`: function that determines the new data types to
      use for each column.
    """
    if skip is None:
        skip = []
    dt = df_shrink_dtypes(df, skip, obj2cat=obj2cat, int2uint=int2uint)
    return df.astype(dt)
```

**Example:**

```py
# Generating dataframe with 100,000 rows, and 5 columns:

nrows = 100_000
cats = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Category": np.random.choice(cats, size=nrows),
     "val1": np.random.randint(1, 8, nrows),
     "val2": np.random.randint(1, 8, nrows),
     "val3": np.random.randint(1, 8, nrows),
     "val4": np.random.randint(1, 8, nrows)}
)

df.dtypes
#
# Category    object
# val1         int64
# val2         int64
# val3         int64
# val4         int64
# dtype: object

# Applying `df_shrink` to `df` columns:
_df = df_shrink(df)

_df.dtypes
#
# Category    category
# val1            int8
# val2            int8
# val3            int8
# val4            int8
# dtype: object

# Comparring memory usage of `df` vs. `_df`:

df.info(memory_usage=True)
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
# Data columns (total 5 columns):
#  #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype 
# ---  ------    --------------   ----- 
#  0   Category  100000 non-null  object
#  1   val1      100000 non-null  int64 
#  2   val2      100000 non-null  int64 
#  3   val3      100000 non-null  int64 
#  4   val4      100000 non-null  int64 
# dtypes: int64(4), object(1)
# memory usage: 3.8+ MB     <---- Original memory footprint

_df.info(memory_usage=True)
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# RangeIndex: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
# Data columns (total 5 columns):
#  #   Column    Non-Null Count   Dtype   
# ---  ------    --------------   -----   
#  0   Category  100000 non-null  category
#  1   val1      100000 non-null  int8    
#  2   val2      100000 non-null  int8    
#  3   val3      100000 non-null  int8    
#  4   val4      100000 non-null  int8    
# dtypes: category(1), int8(4)
# memory usage: 488.8 KB     <---- Almost 8x reduction!
```

### Using [`numba`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/) to generate an optimized machine code version of `my_cal` function

To install [`numba`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/) on your Python environment, execute the following command:

```
pip install -U numba
```

To use Numba with pandas, you'll have to define `my_cal`, decorating it with `@jit`. You'll also need to pass the underlying `grp` values as NumPy arrays. You can do so by using the `to_numpy()` method. Here's an example on how your function should look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numba

# NOTE: define each column separately, and inform each data type, to improve performance.
@numba.jit
def my_cal(val1: int, val2: int, val3: int, val4: int):
    return val1 + val2 + val3 + val4

# Using numba optimized version of `my_cal`:

%%timeit
_df.groupby('Category').apply(
    lambda grp: my_cal(
        grp['val1'].to_numpy(),
        grp['val2'].to_numpy(),
        grp['val3'].to_numpy(),
        grp['val4'].to_numpy(),
    )
).to_dict()
# 6.33 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

### Execution time comparison

The following code compares the different ways we could implement the `DataFrame.groupby/apply` operation:

```py
# OPTION 1: original implementation
df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda grp: grp.sum(numeric_only=True)).to_dict()
# 18.9 ms ± 500 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# OPTION 2: original implementation with memory optimized dataframe
_df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda grp
grp.sum(numeric_only=True)).to_dict()
# 9.96 ms ± 140 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# OPTION 3: Using numba optimized `my_cal` function, with memory optimized dataframe
_df.groupby('Category').apply(
    lambda grp: my_cal(
        grp['val1'].to_numpy(),
        grp['val2'].to_numpy(),
        grp['val3'].to_numpy(),
        grp['val4'].to_numpy(),
    )
).to_dict()
# 6.33 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Results Summary:**

| Implementation | Execution Time Per Loop |
| --- | --- |
| OPTION 1 | 18.9 ms ± 500 µs |
| OPTION 2 | 9.96 ms ± 140 µs |
| OPTION 3 | 6.33 ms ± 221 µs |

## Edit: using `numba` to optimize `my_cal` function

### Caveats

Numba is best at accelerating **functions that apply numerical functions to NumPy arrays**. If you try to `@jit` a function that contains unsupported Python or NumPy code, compilation will revert object mode which will mostly likely not speed up your function.
The warning you're receiving is because `my_cal` is calling an inner function that is not being `@jit` optimized, and therefore, numba is unable to optimize your code. If you have access and can make changes to `inner_cal`, then you could try also including the `@jit` decorator to it and specifying its parameters type hints.
The problem with that approach is that if `inner_cal` contains calls to other functions, you'll have to do the same thing to these other functions. Before you chose to convert all inner functions to numba, I strongly suggest you analyze your code, to determine if those inner functions are also operating on top of numpy arrays. Otherwise it's a waste of time.

To give you an example, here's how your `inner_cal` function should look like, If you use `numba`:

```py
@numba.jit
def inner_cal(val1: float, val2: float, val3: float, val4: float) -> float:
    return val1 + val2 + val3 + val4


@numba.jit
def my_cal(val1: float, val2: float, val3: float, val4: float) -> dict:
    ret = inner_cal(val1, val2, val3, val4) # inner_cal is in external library
    return {'cal': ret}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying with many options, I have tried OPTION 3. It's first time to use `numba` and got a warning `Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "my_cal" failed type inference due to: Untyped global name 'inner_func_in_my_cal': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'>`. It seems it is caused by the inner function which calls some other function inside `my_cal`.
While searching this warning I got to know `swifter` package. This helps doing parallel processing in dataframe, and execution time is reduced about 30%.

Comment: @W.Cointreau have you specified the `my_cal` parameters type hints? It should look something like this: `def my_cal(val1: int, val2: int, val3: int, val4: int):`

Comment: @W.Cointreau If you add the source code of your `my_cal` function to your question, I can help you with that

Comment: I updated my question. And, I specified type hints and have warning messages.

Comment: If I do OPTION 2, do I lose some accuracy of my data? my columns are float64

Comment: @W.Cointreau regarding the option 2, you don't lose any accuracy. The values are only converted to a smaller data type when that data type can handle the range of values that exist inside the column. If you have a float64 column, and its values can't fit inside float32, then the column is left unchanged. By default, Pandas uses float64, and int64, regardless if you have two unique values inside a column or 100k unique values.

Comment: @W.Cointreau I've edited my answer to further explain why you're getting the numba warning

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make changes in `inner_cal`... I tried OPTION 2 in my data and could see the types of columns are converted from float64 to float32. And actually the data in each column is changed at the 5th to 6th decimal place level. Memory usage was reduced about 30% but there was no significant change in time.